# How to use stringr functions to remove all empty words?

Tags: r

```
b <- c("books",  "  ",  "animals",  "frogs")

#My code: 
b[!grepl("^\\s+$", b)]
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"   

#Now, I am working to figure out this solution with stringr package.
str_remove_all(b, "^\\s+$")
[1] "books"   ""          "animals" "frogs"
```

The output shows `""` where my new code fails. Any solution to get the result like my first code?

Comment: `b[nzchar(trimws(b))]`

Answer (score 3):

We may use `str_subset` in `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(b, "^\\s+$", negate = TRUE)
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

The function that corresponds to `grepl` is `str_detect`

```
b[str_detect(b, "^\\s+$", negate = TRUE)]
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

---

In `base R`, we may use `grep` with `invert = TRUE`

```
grep("^\\s+$", b, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

Or without regex with `trimws` (to remove the spaces - leading/lagging) and use `nzhcar` to create logical vector for subsetting

```
b[nzchar(trimws(b))]
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

Answer (score 2):

Two base R alternatives:

```r
b[nzchar(trimws(b))]
# [1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"  
b[grepl("\\S",b)]
# [1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R` we can do:

```
b[b !=" "]
```

Output:

```
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```

**OR** with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(str_squish(b), "")
```

```
[1] "books"   "animals" "frogs"
```